# Server-based DataTables + YADCF with AJAX-based select2: selecting option clears Select2 selection

Tags: datatables, yadcf

The set-up:

1. DataTables is using remote data with pagination (AJAX-based)
2. YADCF is using a Select2 that's grabbing options using AJAX call
3. Selecting Select2 option triggers grid refresh and filtering (everything is correct)

The problem:

Right after DataTables pulls the updated rowset, YADCF re-runs its intialization routine and Select2 loses its state (i.e. the selected option is no longer selected and is not in the DOM anymore).

*This:*

[image: GOOD STATE]

*becomes this after grid reloads (select2 control re-initialized and lost all options pulled via AJAX, including the one that was selected):*
[image: BAD STATE]

**How can I avoid YADCF re-initialization in such case?**

Having debugged the problem for a while I found that `function appendFilters(...)` is called after each grid refresh from this YADCF line:

https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L3332

which, in turn is fired by DataTables' `draw` event.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

DataTables config array:

```
var dataTableConfig = {
    "autoWidth": false,
    "deferLoading": 220,
    "pageLength": 5,
    "searchDelay": 0,
    "searching": true,
    "placeholder": null,
    "ordering": true,
    "paging": true,
    "info": true,
    "columns": [
        {
            "name": "company",
            "data": {
                "_": "company",
                "filter": "company",
                "display": "company"
            },
            "visible": true,
            "searchable": true,
            "orderable": true,
            "className": "column_Company"
        }
    ],
    "showGlobalSearch": true,
    "enableColumnFilter": true,
    "columnFilterPosition": "table",
    "resetPaging": true,
    "select": {
        "style": "single"
    },
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/datasource/",
        "type": "post"
    }
};
```

**YADCF INIT:**

```
colCfg = [
    {
        "column_number": 2,
        "filter_type": "select",
        "data": [],
        "filter_default_label": "(select..)",
        "enable_auto_complete": false,
        "sort_as": "alpha",
        "sort_order": "asc",
        "filter_match_mode": "contains",
        "exclude_label": "exclude",
        "select_type": "select2",
        "select_type_options": {
            "width": "300",
            ajax: {
                url: '/datasource/',
                dataType: 'json',
                method: 'post',
                delay: 750,
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        q: params.term,
                        page: params.page
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data, params) {
                    params.page = params.page || 1;
                    return {
                        results: data.results,
                        pagination: {
                            more: (params.page * 20) < data.total_count
                        }
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            },
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            templateResult: formatItem,
            templateSelection: formatItemSelection,
            escapeMarkup: function(v) {return v;}
        },
        "case_insensitive": true,
        "filter_delay": 500
    }
];
yadcf.init(dataTable, colCfg);
```

Comment: What's the reason YADCF re-inits column filters after each grid redraw?

Comment: please post the relevant code of your dt and yadcf constructors/init code, and explain how is your select2 gets its data - is it from dt source just like any other filters or is it using its own ajax source?

Comment: Updated.

 select2 uses exactly this approach: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax

Comment: haven't tried that approach before, I suggest you to find out how you could force select2 to pull the data from its ajax source and add the needed line of code in yadcf or let me know how to make it do so. b.t.w you can provide the needed input for select2 along with your datatables data source as described on the showcase http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/server_side_source.html

Comment: I'll take a close look at select2. but why do you re-initialize column filters on every grid redraw - wouldn't doing it once be enough?

Comment: I do the *re-initialization* as a response to dt draw/server side data load / etc events, I agree that I can double check if it can be reduced, anyway for now I advice you to read your filter data from the JSON you already pass to dt, like I'm doing it on the showcase http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/server_side_source.html.